# How do I perform a similar query using SQLDF?

Tags: r, sqldf

I have two data sets, the first one has uniform 5 digit zip-codes and the second one has 9 code zip-code format, I used the following query in SQL and it worked perfectly, SQLDF in R doesn't allow concat function what should I use instead to make it work?

`Mapping = sqldf("SELECT * FROM WalmartStores wm INNER JOIN COUNTY_MAPPING cm ON wm.store_zip LIKE concat(cm.zip,"%")")`

Comment: @RuiBarradas can you elaborate a bit more, don't think paste works inside sqldf

Comment: RIght, sorry. Try `cm.zip || "%"` and put the entire command between single quotes.